# Get path relative to batch file - not working directory

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a batch file in E:\dir0\dir1 that calls exe0.exe in that folder. I need the first argument to the exe to be E:\dir0\dir2\dir3\script.js.

The problem is that the name of dir0 (and whatever parent directories it has) as well as the drive letter can change. I've gotten as far as:

```
exe0.exe %~d0\dir0\dir2\dir3\script.js %*
```

Now I just need to make that a relative path somehow (with \.. ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, it sounds like you're describing a folder structure that looks about like this:

```
{unknown}\dir0\dir1\batfile.bat
{unknown}\dir0\dir1\exe0.exe
{unknown}\dir0\dir2\dir3\script.js
```

A very simple way to do this is to avoid using drive letters, and instead use relative path, like this:

```
exe0.exe ..\dir2\dir3\script.js
```

However, if your exe is expecting to get a full drive and path as it's parameter, then you'll need a little more.  Something like this will work:

```
pushd ..\dir2\dir3\script.js
set "ScriptDir=%cd%"
popd
exe0.exe "%ScriptDir%"
```